# Drag and drop audio outside of browser

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to export an audio clip to a DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) without having to download the audio clip and then drag and drop that file from local download folder to the DAW.

Is it possible to drag and drop an audio clip outside the browser just like it is possible with images?

So far, I've found no resource about this, nor have I got any leads on how to achieve this.

Comment: This probably depends on what kind of drag & drop input your DAW supports.

Comment: @Siguza I'm currently testing with Ableton and FL Studio as reference, none seems to process `a` tag pointing to the audio clip.

Comment: A web browser's web page normally run in a sandbox so a page by itself doesn't have any way to interact with your filesystem and folders it can send a file which your browser can download to a predefined path like "Downloads". But using extension API you can leverage this surely there might be already some extension available in chrome store give it a try. Once you find something that works you can inspect its source code incase interested